# Bivariate Lognormal Distribution

Tags: probability

Is there a pdf for bivariate lognormal distribution? 
Suppose there are 2 random variable $X_1$ and $X_2$  with standard normal distribution, how would the pdf of a bivariate lognormal distribution look like?

Thanks!

Comment: If $X_1$, $X_2$ are normally distributed, why would you expect their joint distribution to be a bivariate lognormal distribution?